# recipe for target 'cinset' failed

Tags: ace, tao

I am trying to install ace and tao following [this](http://wiki.icub.org/wiki/Compiling_ACE) tutorial and [this](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/DOC_ROOT/ACE/ACE-INSTALL.html#unix) one. But after i enter "make" command from TAO_wrapper directory, i get below error:

```
 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/robot/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/robot/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/src'

GNUmakefile: /home/robot/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/src/GNUmakefile.gperf MAKEFLAGS=w

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/robot/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/src'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/robot/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/tests'

GNUmakefile: /home/robot/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/tests/GNUmakefile.cinset MAKEFLAGS=w

g++ -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wnon-virtual-dtor -O3 -ggdb -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -W -Wpointer-arith -pipe -D_GNU_SOURCE   -I/home/robot/ACE_wrappers -D__ACE_INLINE__ -I../../..  -c -o .obj/c.o /home/robot/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/tests/c.cpp
g++ -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wnon-virtual-dtor -O3 -ggdb -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -W -Wpointer-arith -pipe -D_GNU_SOURCE   -I/home/robot/ACE_wrappers -D__ACE_INLINE__ -I../../..  -c -o .obj/test.o /home/robot/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/tests/test.cpp
g++ -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wnon-virtual-dtor -O3 -ggdb -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -W -Wpointer-arith -pipe -D_GNU_SOURCE   -I/home/robot/ACE_wrappers -D__ACE_INLINE__ -I../../..  -Wl,-E -L/home/robot/ACE_wrappers/lib -L.  -L../../../lib  -o cout .obj/c.o .obj/test.o -lACE -ldl -lrt 
.obj/test.o: In function `main':
/home/robot/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/tests/test.cpp:24: undefined reference to `in_word_set(char const*, unsigned int)'
/home/robot/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/tests/test.cpp:24: undefined reference to `in_word_set(char const*, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
GNUmakefile.cinset:196: recipe for target 'cout' failed
make[1]: *** [cout] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/robot/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/tests'
GNUmakefile:1241: recipe for target 'cinset' failed
make: *** [cinset] Error 2
```

When i compile the gperf, ace packaes individually i didn't get any error. But when i try to compile the hole ACE_wrapper package i get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something got messed up on your file system. As this is just an unit test this should not be a problem to ignore. As alternative you can run `make realclean` and `make`.